# Barra superior VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

É possivel remover ou esconder essa barra que fica com o nome do projeto do VS Code? Utilizo Ubuntu 19.04

[image: Essa parte circulada em vermelho]

Comment: Mas se vc esconder essa barra para onde vão ir os btns de Minimizar, Fechar, Etc?

Comment: Eles ficavam flutuando perto da barra de atividade mas não me lembro como fazer isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que mudar o `window title bar` para `custom`, para isso siga os passos da imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]